# SQL - delete duplicates with null values WITHOUT row_number

Tags: sqlite, group-by, null, duplicates, sql-delete

I am using SQLite and I have the following table, x, which contains about 300k rows, here is a sample:

| name | surname | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeniffer | Doe | Jenny |
| Jeniffer | Doe | NULL |
| Jeniffer | Doe | Jenny |

Each row has Name, Surname and Nickname values, where Nickname can also be NULL. None of the values are unique and there is also no key. What I want to do is delete the "duplicates" where Nickname is NULL, while grouping them by the Name-Surname pair but also delete the "actual" duplicates.

This would be the expected output:

| name | surname | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeniffer | Doe | Jenny |

I have tried using the following query:

```sql
select x.* 
from (select x.*, 
          row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by nickname nulls last) as seqnum
     from x)
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

but unfortunately I get an error:

> near "(": syntax error

I have searched for days now looking for an answer and I still cannot figure it out. I am using SQLite3, if it matters. I still am not sure why is there syntax error, I assume it has something to do with the `row_number()`, but according to my search on the web, it should be supported with sqlite3 (In my case it is not as far as I understood it)

So now I am looking for a way to modify this query in order to get the desired output, but I am clueless for days now...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replace `) x` with `AS x`

Comment: and `NULLS LAST` does not appear to be supported by sqlite: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=45c7af025151b870b978fdbb17180681

Comment: Probably your version of SQLite does not support window functions which were introduced in version 3.25.0 and/or `nulls last` which was introduced in version 3.30.0

Comment: Show the result of: `select sqlite_version();`

Comment: Hi, the result is following: 3.15.2

Comment: Ok.  That is rather old and, as @forpas mentioned, doesn't support some of the features you are using.  Can you update?  If not, you'll need to replace the window function also.  Do you have a primary key for this table?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it is and no, unfortunately I cannot update it. I don't have a primary key, but the combination of name-surname is always unique.

Comment: What if you have the same (name, surname) with multiple non-null nicknames?

Comment: Hi, the data that I am processing does not have such case (at least not yet)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have created the table [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), there is a column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) in the table that acts like the primary key.

You can use aggregation to get the min `rowid` of each combination of `name` and `surname` that should not be deleted:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT COALESCE(
           MIN(CASE WHEN nickname IS NOT NULL THEN rowid END),
           MIN(rowid)
         )  
  FROM tablename 
  GROUP BY name, surname
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9e18436067eb836df027db5533625588).

Answer (score 1):

For 3.15, you might try something like this, which avoids window functions, NULLS LAST, etc:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=52049598dadc1ef55c07d60e4c74fd5e)

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
  FROM x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 FROM x AS x1
            WHERE (x.name,  x.surname) = (x1.name,  x1.surname)
              AND COALESCE(x.nickname, x1.nickname || 'x')
                > COALESCE(x1.nickname, x.nickname || 'x')
       )
;
```

The result:

| name | surname | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeniffer | Doe | Jenny |

For newer versions of sqlite:

`order by nickname IS NULL, nickname` addresses the `NULLS LAST` requirement, since `nickname IS NULL` yields 0 for false and 1 for true, so the null cases are ordered last.

```
select x.* 
  from (
         select x.*
              , row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by nickname IS NULL, nickname) as seqnum
           from x
       ) AS x
 where seqnum = 1
;
```

The test case:

```
WITH x (name, surname, nickname) AS (
        SELECT 'Jeniffer',  'Doe',         'Jenny' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Jeniffer',  'Doe',         NULL    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Jeniffer',  'Doe',         'Jenny'
     )
select x.* 
  from (
         select x.*
              , row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by nickname is null, nickname) as seqnum
           from x
       ) AS x
 where seqnum = 1
;
```

The result:

| name | surname | nickname | seqnum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeniffer | Doe | Jenny | 1 |

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I still get the same error: near "(": syntax error

Comment: @takibu What version of sqlite are you using?  Maybe your problem is not just the SQL.  How are you executing it?